# Prove that $\bar F=F^\text{sep}F^{p^{-\infty}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem goes as follows. Let $F$ be a field, $\bar F$ be its algebraic closure, $F^\text{sep}$ be its separable closure, and $F^{p^{-\infty}}$ be the subfield of $\bar F$ containing all purely inseparable elements. Show that $\bar F$ is equal to the compositum of $F^\text{sep}$ and $F^{p^{-\infty}}$.

I know that this is equivalent to showing that $\bar F$ is separable over $F^{p^{-\infty}}$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L=F^{p^{-\infty}}$ to save typing and let $a\in\bar F \setminus L$.  Then there is no $n$ with $a^{p^n}\in L$ since then for some $m$ we would have $a^{p^{m+n}}\in F$ contradicting $a\notin L$.  Now suppose the minimal polynomial $f$ of $a$ over $L$ were not separable. Then $f=g^p$ for some $g\in L[a][X]$.  But since the $p^{th}$ powers of the coefficients of $g$ are in $L$, its coefficients are in $L$ (by the definition of $L$).  Thus, $g\in L[X]$, and so $f$ is not irreducible in $L[X]$, which is a contradiction, since it was chosen as a minimal polynomial.  Thus $a$ is separable over $L$.  Since $a$ was arbitrary in $\bar F$, $\bar F$ is separable over $L$.

This shows that $\bar F$=$L^{sep}$.  It's not immediately obvious to me that it shows $\bar F$ is the compositum of $F^{sep}$ and $L$, but it's been a long time since I studied any of this.  Anyway, I'm glad I was able to help with the part that wasn't obvious to you.

Comment: Why is $f=g^p$ for some $g\in L[a][X]$？I only know that $f(X)=g(X^{p^r})$ for some $g\in L[X]$ and $r\ge1$ an integer.

Comment: $f\in L[X]$ with only terms in multiples of $p$.  Since $L$ contains $p^{th}$ roots of all its elements, take the $p^{th}$ roots of all the coefficients and divide all exponents by $p$ to get $g\in L[X]$ with $f=g^p$ (since the characteristic of the field is $p$ we have $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$.

Comment: For example, if $f=rx^{2p}+sx^p+t$ then $g=ux^2+vx+w$ where $u^p=r$, $v^p=s$, and $w^p=t$, gives $f=g^p$.

Comment: I see. I was originally confused by the $L[a][X]$. Thanks.